# I'm not able to use element or browser.get commands (using windows 7)

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
it('login page', function() {
    browser.driver.get('url');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('j_username')).sendKeys('admin');
    //browser.driver.sleep(4000);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('j_password')).sendKeys('admin');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.className('btn-sign-in')).click();
  });
```

I can run above code successfully but when I use this as -

```
it('login page', function() {
    browser..get('url');

    element(by.name('j_username')).sendKeys('admin');

    element(by.name('j_password')).sendKeys('admin');
    element(by.className('btn-sign-in')).click();
  });
```

I'm not able to run it.

Similarly when I try to use it in elementexplorer.js, it doesn't work -

```
> element(by.id('username'))
{ click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  findElements: [Function],
  isElementPresent: [Function],
  evaluate: [Function],
  '$$': [Function],
  findElement: [Function],
  find: [Function],
  isPresent: [Function],
  element: { [Function] all: [Function] },
  '$': [Function] }
```

This means this is not working in it as well.

Comment: Do you get an error message? You have a typo at `browser..get('url');` (double point) instead of `browser.get('url');`

Comment: sorry that is my typo, it is correctly written in my actual code.

Comment: no problem ;) which error do you get?

Comment: Message:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page

Comment: I tried browser.waitForAngular() as well

Comment: which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: This is strange...Have you started your webserver before running your tests?

Comment: Yes, for sure.....because it works for me when I use the code given in first snippet i.e. with browser.driver.

Comment: Is your Protractor up to date? Latest version is 0.20.1.

**NB for moderation:** I can't move this discussion to chat since this user doesn't have the requested reputation yet. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK, so I'm missing something but don't have ideas anymore. If you followed all [Protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/docs) recommandations, you could open an issue on GitHub. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This is something that confuses a lot of people when they use the element explorer. When you use something like `element(by.id('username'))` protractor will not immediately execute it. You need to call a function on the element to test it.

Do something like:

```
element(by.id('username')).getAttribute('value')
```

Then then element explorer will tell you if it works or not.